# Difference in .NET Protocol Buffer libraries

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers

At the moment, there are two proto buf libraries for .NET:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/ With Jon Skeet as the owner
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ with Marc Gravell as the owner

What is the difference between the two?  Are both coded to the same spec as the Google spec? Are there any differences?

The reason I ask is that currently we have proto buf interop between services that use the Java and potentially C++ libraries and want to make sure we avoid any problems or edge cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jon's version is largely a port of the Java version, so has a very similar API and design approach. It is also AFAIK entirely contract-first, i.e. from .proto.

My version comes at it more from a .NET perspective, looking at what is common in .NET serializers - so mutable objects, retrofit to existing types, code-first (although it *can* still do code-gen from a .proto if you want), etc. It can even infer data from the attributes used by `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` to work side-by-side with existing code, and can plug into both remoting (via `ISerializable`) and WCF (via attributes or configuration). So it is deeply rooted in the .NET ecosystem. I also include *inheritance* support (since that is so common in the other .NET serializers), but this is a bit fiddly to map to other platforms since it has no direct representation in .proto.

The binary data should be identical; that is largely the point of the format ;p It is largely a choice of which API might be more appropriate to you.

For your needs, working side-by-side with C++ and Java code in the same system, and with existing .proto definitions, I suggest Jon's version may be the most appropriate option for you.

If, however, you are doing .NET *only*, or are doing .NET with interop with *external* code (i.e. you don't care what language the "other side" uses, since you only have to worry about your own code), then IMO protobuf-net can be a pretty pain free way to consume the data; **especially** if you have an existing system that you now find you want to serialize (or: serialize faster / smaller).

Comment: Thanks Marc. We have used your version from day 1, but was looking for some clarification especially as more teams start using the libraries.

Comment: @Ray then keep using it and enjoy ;p